# Justified text in a cell table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm not sure about how to name my problem, but what I would like to achieve is (in a beamer frame) two columns, one consisting of mathematical objects, the other one facing it describing the objects. The problem I encounter is that I can't seem to justify the text of the right column.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9cm}}
 (X, \mathcal{X}) & a metric space of alternatives and its Borel $\sigma$-algebra\\
 \mathbf{Q} & a metric space of budgets, seen as an index \\
\mathbf{B}(q) & a non-empty set in $\mathcal{X}$, denoting the possible alternatives given a budget $q \in \mathbf{Q}$ \\
\mathbf{d} :\mathbf{Q} \to \mathcal{X} & a decision function, $\emptyset \subset \mathbf{d}(q) \subseteq \mathbf{B}(q)$, decisive if $\# \mathbf{d}(q) = 1$ \\
(q, \mathbf{C}) & a trial, $q \in \mathbf{Q}$ and $C \in \mathcal{X}$, that is a succes if $\mathbf{d}(q) \subseteq \mathbf{C}$, failure if $d(q) \cap \mathbf{C} = \emptyset$, partial success if $\mathbf{d}(q) \cap \mathbf{C} \neq \emptyset$ \\
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is what I get, the right column isn't justified]

Anyone would have an idea to justify the text of the right column?

Sincerely,

Olivier

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Try removing the `\raggedright`.

Comment: while removing `\raggedright` will do what you ask, please rethink this decision.  the right-hand edge of the column may look nice and even, but the internal spacing may well make the affected entries harder to read than if the interword spacing is uniform.  this can make math (which can be hard enough to interpret under normal circumstances) nearly unintelligible.

Comment: You are right it happened to be not that great for a line, I opted for a more literal writting. Thank you!
Edit: I also added a spacing between lines to make it clearer with 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

Comment: You also can use the directive `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package, which allows for hyphenation, but not at the cost of a non-uniform spacing.